# VNC Desktop for 16.04 with adjustable geometry fail

Tags: unity, gnome, xfce, vnc, randr

I have tried several online solutions, no go.

1) Unity or Gnome attempts give only grey screen

2) xfce4 works but randr extension is not present (it is present & working for Unity)

- tightvnc installed
- all packages updated to latest
- supermicro server board and stock driver from install

For 2, what I have read suggests it has to do with the display driver. 
I am going through the manuals, so far no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT LOGFILE:

```
22/04/17 10:01:14 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
22/04/17 10:01:14 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
22/04/17 10:01:14 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
22/04/17 10:01:14 All Rights Reserved.
22/04/17 10:01:14 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
22/04/17 10:01:14 Desktop name 'X' (Vgpgpu:1)
22/04/17 10:01:14 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
22/04/17 10:01:14 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
gpg-agent[8433]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:8425): xfce4-session-WARNING **: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XRender extension.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XRandr extension.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XComposite extension.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XDamage extension.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XFixes extension.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: Compositing manager disabled.

(xfwm4:8435): xfwm4-WARNING **: Cannot find visual format on screen 0
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".

(xfsettingsd:8445): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: No RANDR extension found in display :1.0. Display settings won't be applied.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1.0".

(xfsettingsd:8445): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: XI is not present.

(xfsettingsd:8445): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: Failed to initialize the Xkb extension.

(xfsettingsd:8445): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: Failed to initialize the Accessibility extension.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding 'XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt><Shift>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding 'XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt><Shift>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding 'XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Alt>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt><Shift>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Binding '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>XF86AudioMute' failed!

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (xfce4-volumed:8528): WARNING **: Failed to map virtual modifiers

** (zeitgeist-datahub:8470): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Failure: Module initialization failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".

** (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:8505): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent:     GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent     already exists for the given subject
Cannot register authentication agent:     GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent     already exists for the given subject
xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
xfdesktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
```

Comment: Do you have to use tightvnc? I had major issues with it (similiar grey screen only) I never got Unity to work, but gnome I was able to just go to settings - sharing and enable screen sharing then connect and it worked. Possibly have to run `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false` to get a connection. But can still require a password to connect.

Comment: Not at all - and in fact someone at my school just let me know about alternatives: X2go and X sessions over SSH. I just tried SSH -X, and it worked excellently right away. Excellent as in much, much faster, since the X rendering is done locally on my Mac with Xquartz. I have spent far too much time on debugging this. I'm done. I will just use SSH or perhaps alternatives from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to not bother. I am using SSH with -X option instead. 
So far seems much better.

Wikipedia shows several other options for remote desktop as well. No need for this headache.  X2go was also recommended.